# Grails syntax for joining tables on composite foreign key

Tags: hibernate, grails

Could anyone please tell me how to join tables in Grails? I need help with the syntax.

Let's say I have three tables and they don't have any explicitly defined foreign key constraints:

```
  EMPLOYEE:
  empid
  name
  emp_deptid
  emp_teamid
  title
  salary
  hiredate
```

```
  DEPT:
  dept_deptid
  deptname
  location
  size
  numOfTeams
```

```
  TEAM:
  team_teamid
  teamname
  team_deptid
  responsibility
  size
```

I want to join EMPLOYEE and TEAM on TEAMID and DEPTID. I know how to join tables in a SQL query. I would actually like to know how to do the table joins in Grails(on these selected columns using OnetoOne, OnetoMany, hasMapped, etc.). thanks

**edit:**

```
Class Emp(){

String empid
String teamid
String deptid
.....
.....
Date   hiredate

Team   team

static mapping = {
    ....
            .... 
    deptid column:'emp_deptid'
    teamid column:'emp_teamid'
    .....
            .....
    team column: ['teamid', 'deptid']
 }


}


Class Team(){
...
...
String teamid
String deptid

static mapping ={
...
deptid column:'team_deptid'
teamid column:'team_teamid'
....
}
}
```

Comment: What does your Grails domain model look like?

Comment: I edited my original post to include the domain classes.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 subsections in [GORM doc section 5.4.1 and 5.4.2](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#5.4%20Querying%20with%20GORM), both named "Querying Associations".

**edit:**

Suddenly, it's not that easy - sorry for being inattentive.

Grails officially supports [syntax for only compound primary keys](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#5.5.2%20Custom%20ORM%20Mapping), not foreign. I found a bunch of issues about composite foreign keys in Grails: [GRAILS-4606](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-4606) and [GRAILS-4256](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-4256).

I can propose approaches that might work, but I didn't test this myself.

A "list of columns" syntax (sample taken from GRAILS-4256):

```
class Employee {
  Team team
  static mapping = {
     // ... column mapping
     team column: [team_id, dept_id]
  }
}
```

Lauro Becker used [custom configuration class](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Composite-foreign-key-td3046351.html) that adds composite foreign key mapping syntax - this looks to have worked for him.

Some people even create updatable database views with a single key field, and map domain to them, not to original tables - but I believe that's an overkill.

Comment: That documentation doesn't explain how to join tables on selected columns. It looks like, that is for tables that have already foreign key relationships.

Comment: Sorry, I was inattentive. Yes, you have to have relationship between those tables - at least in mapping. Custom foreign keys mapping is described in section "5.5.2.1 Table and Column Names". Let me update the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I edited my original post to add mapping DSL. I am getting "ERROR util.JDBCExceptionReporter - ORA-00972: identifier is too long" error while doing GET on the web service that uses the Dept and Team domains. Looks like my mapping DSL is not right. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: That sounds like a different question. Anyway, if you have a single column name mapping, you don't need to use lists, just write `dept column: 'deptid'`. Maybe the list-of-columns foreign key syntax is not supported after all, and GORM tries to find a column named after a `toString()` of `List`.

Comment: Thanks, Victor. Since I was getting error with team/dept mapping, I wanted to give a try on the emp/team mapping(original post updated). With his mapping I get - ERROR util.JDBCExceptionReporter - ORA-00904: "THIS_"."teamid, deptid": invalid identifier error. Show_sql produces: select this_.id as id1_0_, this_.version as version1_0_, this_.emp_deptid as emp3_1_0_, this_.empid as empid1_0_, this_.hiredate as hiredate1_0_, this_.name as name1_0_, this_.salary as salary1_0_, this_."teamid, deptid" as teamid8_1_0_, this_.emp_teamid as emp9_1_0_, this_.title as title1_0_ from emp this_

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to query and join in grails.  Here's one example of a simple way to do a SQL join of two tables:

```
class Dept {
    ...
}

class Team {
    ...
    Dept dept
}

Team.list(fetch: [dept: 'eager'])
```

Comment: Why the eager fetching? Doesn't really have anything to do with the original question.

Comment: Without eager fetching, it wouldn't do a SQL join.  Maybe I misunderstood joining as the focus of the question.

Comment: If you mean "associate domain objects with each other" by join, yes.  Eager fetching means when you run `list` on `Team`, the SQL query will join the `Dept` table on `dept_id` and load `Dept` records along with `Team` records.  Without eager fetching, you'd have to load the `Dept` objects with a second query.

Comment: I understand how eager fetching works. My understanding is, it automatically joins tables if they have foreign key constraints defined already. In my case, there is no foreign key relationship defined already in the tables. So my question is, how will Grails/GORM know that which columns in those tables need to be joined?

Comment: If a domain object has a member that's another domain object, has a `belongsTo`, or is listed in another objects `hasMany`/`hasOne`, then there's a relationship.  Grails uses the field names to figure out the key names.  E.g. if domain object `Team` has a `Dept` object called `myDept`, grails will join on a key named `my_dept_id`.  It can be overridden in the mapping DSL if necessary.

Comment: Foreign key constraints on the database are optional.  They might be used by the `db-reverse-engineer` plugin but as far as I know, GORM ignores them.

Comment: Foreign key constraints are constraints, i.e. they enforce rules. They're there to make sure that you don't insert a record that has an invalid reference to another table. So they're not useful to GORM, they're used by the database.

Comment: In my abovementioned example, the column names on which I want to join the tables are same. Whatif the column names are different. Let's say I have dept_deptid(instead of deptid) in the DEPT table, and team_teamid (instead of teamid) and team_deptid(instead of deptid) in the TEAM table. On cases like this, how will Grails identify the key columns that need to be joined. Because, I have several legacy tables that are having inconsistent names on which they can be joined. Am I missing something?

Comment: Using the mapping DSL, you can specify the column to join on: `static mapping = { dept column:'dept_deptid' }`.  Take a look at the documentation [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20%28GORM%29.html#5.5.2.1%20Table%20and%20Column%20Names).

Comment: @Taylor: I edited my original post (please take a look at that). But I am getting "ERROR util.JDBCExceptionReporter - ORA-00972: identifier is too long" error while doing GET on the web service that uses the Dept and Team domains.

Comment: you need to make sure not to have TEXT as mapping type. you need varchar(X) with small size to be able to create an index on that column...